# Seeking Feedback on Jeffrey Kaplan's YouTube Philosophy Lectures

Tags: education

I hope this post finds you well. I recently stumbled upon Jeffrey Kaplan's philosophy lectures on YouTube, and I'm curious if anyone with academic credit has watched them and can offer some feedback.

I used to have a lot of confidence in my ability to evaluate the quality of educational content, but as I get older, I find myself doubting my judgment. I had some philosophy courses in college and stayed in school longer than most, but now that I'm in my 30s, I'm not sure if my evaluations are still reliable.

On a lazy Sunday, I find myself entertained by watching philosophy lectures, but I don't want to waste my time on something that isn't worth it. So, I'm hoping someone with some academic background can share their thoughts on Jeffrey Kaplan's lectures and help me decide if they are worth watching.

Thank you in advance for your help and input!